# View nao comunica com o MB

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou usando Primefaces,JavaJPA,e Wildfly, nao tem muito haver mas minha duvida é a seguinte: 
a minha view nao esta enxergando o meu MB, quando rodo dá o seguinte erro:

> Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginMB' resolved to null

estou usando as seguinte anotações no meu MB:

> @ManagedBean (name = "loginMB") 
>   @ViewScoped

Comment: Ola Pedro, você não usa CDI? qual é o import que você usa para @ViewScoped?

Comment: Dilnei estou usando CDI, o import que estou usando é o  "import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;"

Answer (score 0):

Se você utiliza CDI você deve usar o named que é um qualifier, basicamente o que ele faz é tornar seu bean acessível através da EL.
O import para o scoped view deve ser **faces.view.ViewScoped** e não **faces.bean.Vie‌​wScoped**

Veja [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbak.html)

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@Named(value = "loginMB")
@ViewScoped
public class LoginMB implements Serializable {
    // cod...
}
```

@ManagedBean é do JSF já esta deprecated.

Ex: de comunicao até o database

```
    @Named(value = "loginMB")
    @ViewScoped
    public class LoginMB implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    SeuServico servico     

    @Transactional
    public void save() {
        servico.salvar(algumObjeto);
     }
}
```

Serviço:

```
public class SeuServico implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    SeuRepository repository;

    public AlgumObjeto salvar(AlgumObjeto AlgumObjeto) {
        return repository.persiste(user);
    }
}
```

Repositorio:

```
@Repository
public class SeuRepository implements Serializable {

    private final EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    public SeuRepository(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public AlgumObjeto persiste(AlgumObjeto algumObjeto) {
        AlgumObjeto = em.merge(algumObjeto);
        em.flush();
        return AlgumObjeto;
    }
}
```

Obs: a anotação repository você não vai encontrar no java, isso porque sou eu que crio ela, eu digo que meus repositórios são dependentes do CDI, no [link](https://gist.github.com/dilnei/83e6cec3dd9d916ca21b) tem ela

Se você se perguntar: Para que ter uma camada de serviços se eles fazem o que meu repositórios fazem? é o que falei acima, se são coisas básicas como salvar, findById é claro que não tem lógica nenhuma, mas se precisar validar se fazer alguns serviços com códigos nada elegantes, é na service que devera ser realizado o trabalho sujo.

Você ainda pode considerar utilizar repositórios genéricos, eu não gosto, não gosto de herança nos repostirórios, mas é coisa minha, sequiser, utilize mas já vai além do escopo da pergunta, abraços.

Comment: Obrigado Dilnei, funcionou! ainda tenho algumas duvidas aqui mas essa parte ja foi solucionada!
Sou novo na programação,voce tem um método a qual eu escrevo no campo (view) e salvo no Banco?Os meus campos no BD já estao criados mas como faço pra digitar na view  e quando clicar no botão salvar salvar no BD?

Comment: Bom Pedro, isso depende muito da arquitetura do software, as vezes aplico certos patterns, mas o básico que você precisa tem em mente é que você deve isolar as camadas, não tenha chamadas diretas de Repositiórios ou DAO's nos managedBean's tenha uma camada de serviços antes, assim qualquer regra de negócio que tenha que ter não fica no bean da view nem no repositório pois este só serve para acessoa a dados,

Comment: Entendi, estou usando tudo separadamente mesmo, é possivel voce me instruir em um DAO e o MB básico para obter os dados já cadastrados no BD e vice-versa?

Comment: relizado update na resposta, abraços.